# How are operations on a long integer interpreted in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, operators

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int x=32;
        long long n;
        long long t=1;
        cin>>n;
        while(x--){
            n=(n^t);
            t=t<<1;
        }
        cout<<n<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input
3
2147483647
1
0

Output
2147483648
4294967294
4294967295

The above code inverts the number and interprets the result as an unsigned integer. Why so? Shouldn't the resultant numbers be negative? 
Further if I use just the negation operator (~) on the number n, in place of the while loop, the result printed is negative.

Output
-2147483648
-2
-1

When the above operations are performed, aren't the binary representation of the numbers the same? Why is it being interpreted differently? Unsigned in the first case and signed in the second? The result produced remains the same when long long is replaced by long.

Can someone explain to me how this works?

Comment: why is t redefined in the loop?

Comment: @XcoderX: That does seem like a bad idea doesn't it?  But `t` inside the loop hides the one in the loop condition.

Comment: Hmm yes.  Okay...

Answer (score 1):

You're inverting 32 bits, one at a time (why, the XOR can invert any set of bits you choose, in a single operation).  Because `long long` is always at least 64 bits, that means you won't have changed the sign bit.

The negation operator does invert all the bits.

When you switch to `long` instead of `long long`, you will be in trouble.  If your platform has a 32-bit `long` (which is the minimum size, but C++ allows more and many real-world C++ platforms have 64-bit long) then your loop will left-shift from the highest magnitude bit, which gives an implementation-dependent result (probably changing the sign), and then the final pass through the loop will shift one more time, resulting in undefined behavior.